# Qual método HTTP utilizar para pesquisar dados usando o request body?

Tags: http, http-request

Antigamente, segundo a RFC2616, que tratava das specs do HTTP/1.1, dizia que o conteúdo de um request body deveria ser ignorado quando o método utilizado fosse o GET. Logo, utilizava-se o POST quando queríamos realizar alguma pesquisa e receber esses dados enviando os filtros atráves do request body.

Entretanto, essa RFC foi substituída em 2014 pelas RFCs 7230-7327, em que remove a restrição de que filtros devem ser passados pela URL. Junto a isso, o método POST assumiu um conceito de que deve ser utilizado para criar entradas no backend.

A minha dúvida é correto utilizarmos o GET, semanticamente falando, para realizarmos uma consulta a um domínio no caso de precisarmos enviar os filtros atráves de um request body? Se não, enviamos através de um POST?